# Websockets, truffle, ganache and react setup issues connection not open on send()

Tags: web3js, ganache

Sometimes I refresh, and it works. Sometimes it just doesn't work.

I tried changing ganache GUI settings to use port 8545 which I read is the WebSockets port but it still won't connect.  ws:127.0.0.1 won't work and neither will http://

This is my truffle config file. The rest of the code is large and won't help much.

```
// See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
// @truffle/hdwallet-provider
// var HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");
const path = require("path");
var HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");

module.exports = {
  // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
  // to customize your Truffle configuration!
  // contracts_directory: "./allMyStuff/someStuff/theContractFolder",
  contracts_build_directory: path.join(__dirname, "/_truffle/build/contracts"),
  // migrations_directory: "./allMyStuff/someStuff/theMigrationsFolder",
  networks: {

    ganache: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      //port: 8545,
      network_id: 5777,
      //network_id: "*",  // Match any network id,
      websockets: false,  //  websockets true breaks TODO:  connection not open on send()
      // wss
    },

  },

};
```

This is some of my code on the actual screen in question.

```
const options = {
  web3: {
    block: false,
    fallback: {
      type: 'ws',
      //url: 'ws://127.0.0.1:8546',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:7545',

    },
  },
  contracts: [MyStringStore],
//   polls: {
//   accounts: IntervalInMilliseconds,
// },
  events: {},
};
```

I don't understand why sometimes it works and I can see drizzle state and sometimes I can't. React native and web3 is very new to me.

I get errors like this:

> 00:06 Contract MyStringStore not found on network ID: undefined
>
> Error fetching accounts:
>
> 00:06 connection not open

Answer (score 1):

I am having real difficulty setting up drizzle as well. One thing I see is that your

```
url: 'http://127.0.0.1:7545',
```

For some reason Drizzle only works with 'ws' as the prefix for such a URL. I am trying to follow [this guide](https://medium.com/giant-machines/ethereum-state-management-with-drizzle-53cdb647677b) by people who got it working.

Answer (score 0):

I think websocket is only available in the command line version. 
Try install and use ganache-cli instead of the gui version.